# get PDF file path from Android internal storage for soap request in android

Tags: android, pdf, soap

I can successfully create a PDF using iText and I am able to store in internal storage with getting file path.

On button click I have to call a service by passing 12 parameters and one of them is a stored PDF file path from the internal storage of the phone.

**PROBLEM** `File not found error` comes in server log even when while debugging through breakpoints on `arg0` parameter.

How do I get the PDF file path to read it as a parameter value?

```
    class Generatepdf extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showDialog(CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String outRes;
            File myInternalFile;
            HttpTransportSE androidTransport = null;
            try {
                final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.xxxx.xxx.com/";
                final String METHOD_NAME = "getPDF";
                final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
                final String WSDL_URL = "http://localhost:8080/services/getpdf?wsdl";
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                PropertyInfo propOne = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propTwo = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propThree = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propFour = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propFive = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propSix = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propSeven = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propEight = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propNine = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propTen = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propEleven = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propTwelve = new PropertyInfo();
                PropertyInfo propThirteen = new PropertyInfo();

//parameter one
                File readpdfFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "/NewPDF_.pdf");

                propOne.setName("arg0");
                propOne.setValue(readpdfFile);
                // propOne.setValue(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/NewPDF_");
                //   propOne.setValue(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/PDF/NewPDF_.pdf");
                request.addProperty(propOne);

//parameter two
                propTwo.setName("arg1");
                propTwo.setValue("xxxxxxxxxxxx (some 12 digit number)");
                request.addProperty(propTwo);
//parameter three
                propThree.setName("arg2");
                propThree.setValue("ACuoAEB6ADmwAIAuADy4AIDCAEWkAIBwAFYwAIBbAFrAAIAqAF9UAIBnAGE8AEBZAGs8AEDmAGu4AIB3AG0wAIA2AHRQAEDFAHS0AIBEAIBMAIDjAIU0AEB6AIcwAIA4AIxYAICKAJCkAEBwAJ50AIBSAKhYAIBwAKoYAECBAKqMAICTAKykAICbALakAI");
                request.addProperty(propThree);
//parameter four
                propFour.setName("arg3");
                propFour.setValue("name");
                request.addProperty(propFour);
//parameter five
                propFive.setName("arg4");
                propFive.setValue("Test");
                request.addProperty(propFive);
//parameter Six
                propSix.setName("arg5");
                propSix.setValue("cityname");
                request.addProperty(propSix);
//parameter Seven
                propSeven.setName("arg6");
                propSeven.setValue("First");
                request.addProperty(propSeven);
//parameter Eight
                propEight.setName("arg7");
                propEight.setValue("BottomRight");
                request.addProperty(propEight);
//parameter Nine
                propNine.setName("arg8");
                propNine.setValue("null");
                request.addProperty(propNine);
//parameter ten
                propTen.setName("arg9");
                propTen.setValue("Biometric");
                request.addProperty(propTen);
//parameter Eleven
                propEleven.setName("arg10");
                propEleven.setValue("false");
                request.addProperty(propEleven);
//parameter Twelve
                propTwelve.setName("arg11");
                propTwelve.setValue("device1341I089864");
                request.addProperty(propTwelve);
//parameter Thirteen
                propThirteen.setName("arg12");
                propThirteen.setValue("true");
                request.addProperty(propThirteen);

//soap method call
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope2 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope2.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                envelope2.implicitTypes = false;
                androidTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);
                androidTransport.debug = true;
                androidTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope2);

                SoapObject response2 = (SoapObject) envelope2.bodyIn;
                String requestDump = androidTransport.requestDump;
                String responseDump = androidTransport.responseDump;

                Log.i("", "Request: " + requestDump);
                Log.i("", "Response: " + responseDump);

                outRes = response2.toString();

                Result= outRes;
                Log.d("Result", Result);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return Result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            removeDialog(CONNECTING_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    responseTxtView15.setText("RESPONSE   " + Result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: "and able to store in internal storage" -- the code in your question refers to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), not [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You may wish to edit your question to show where you are creating this PDF file.

Comment: did you add the permission at the manifest file ?

Comment: @Ben_Gratvol I am not sure but check this. You have stored your pdf file in internal storage. But passing some other external path in server call. Can u check that

Comment: ok first thing first check in the manifest.xml file  in your project if you put this line in   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: i have added both read and write permissions.

Comment: @CommonsWare Testing device has no external storage. everything's stored in phone memory only.

Comment: "Testing device has no external storage" -- that is very unlikely. "everything's stored in phone memory only" -- "phone memory" refers to both internal storage and external storage. You may wish to consider reading the blog posts that I linked to in my original comment, to learn the difference between internal storage and external storage. Also, you may wish to edit your question to show where you are creating this PDF file.